# Somar valores de resultados no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Estou dando manutenção em um banco e estou encontrando dificuldade em fazer um *select*.

Estrutura da tabela `descontos_taxas`:
      **id | valor | cliente | data_criado**

Meu cenário: Essa tabela guarda tanto taxas quanto descontos na mesma tabela. As taxas são valores positivos e os descontos valores negativos.
Eu preciso pegar todos os valores de todos os clientes, porém, se um cliente tiver recebido uma taxa e um desconto no mesmo dia preciso obter apenas um resultado com a diferença entre os dois.

Até agora fiz o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM 
    descontos_taxas as dt
WHERE 
    YEAR(dt.data_criado) = 2014 and MONTH(dt.data_criado) = 04 and dt.valor < 0
GROUP BY 
    dt.data_criado, dt.cliente
ORDER BY 
    data_criado asc;
```

**Como retornar apenas os valores negativos do resultado da soma entre taxas e descontos aplicados ao mesmo cliente?** (Os clientes que não tiverem taxas aplicadas no mesmo dia do desconto o valor seria somado a 0).

Tenho este resultado no select:

```
 valor |    cliente    | data_criado
-19,90 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-01
  9,90 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-01
-19,90 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-05
-19,90 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-19
```

Preciso que este resultado seja igual a este:

```
 valor |    cliente    | data_criado
-10,00 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-01 //aqui estão os dados das tuplas 1 e 2 somados
-19,90 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-05
-19,90 | Erlon Charles | 2014-04-19
```

Comment: o que acontece se você usar a função `SUM()` do mysql?

Comment: Não obtive o valor correto, verifiquei em alguns clientes e era retornado apenas o valor do desconto e não o valor da diferença. Exemplo: uma taxa de 19,90 e um desconto de -19,90, o *select* retorna -19,90 quando era pra retornar 0,00.

Comment: Importante, no banco os valores são gravados com sinal . Senão sera preciso usar um case, algo como (case when tipo='D' then valor * -1 else valor end)

Comment: Sim os valores são gravados com sinal.
Atualizei a pergunta inserindo um exemplo de o q eu tenho e de o que eu preciso retornar.

Comment: Já foi feito isso na minha resposta, qual é a sua dúvida outra coisa o id nem pode aparecer ai !!!

Comment: Ainda vou reproduzir sua resposta @FCCDias, estava respondendo a pergunta dos outros antes de testar sua resposta, assim que eu conferir eu posto minhas considerações e se estiver correto eu marco, tudo bem?

Comment: Claro @ErlonCharles, mas, o meu intuito não é pontuação foi ajudar e minha preocupação é se você tinha testado ok!

Comment: Eu sei, mas marcar como correto vai ajudar a direcionar quem abrir essa pergunta no futuro

Comment: Agora eu não sei pra quem q eu marco como correta, fiz os teste e precisei usar o `HAVING` sugerido pelo @bacco e as somas sugeridas pelo @fccdias para solucionar meu problema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adicionei o having para filtrar após o group, e a separação de taxas e descontos:

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF( valor > 0, valor, 0 ) ) AS taxas,
    SUM( IF( valor < 0, -valor, 0 ) ) AS descontos,
    SUM(valor) AS total,
    cliente,
    data_criado
FROM
    descontos_taxas
WHERE
    YEAR(data_criado) = 2014 and MONTH(data_criado) = 04
GROUP BY
    cliente, data_criado
ORDER BY
    data_criado asc
HAVING
    total < 0;
```

Comment: é `data_criado` mesmo

Comment: da forma simples ele me retorna o seguinte erro `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`, quando eu vou filtrar apenas os negativos.

Comment: ooops, vacilo meu.

Comment: Eu entendo a dificuldade em entender o que eu estou pedindo, eu mesmo passei uma manhã para consegui interpretar o que o financeiro queria no relatório antes de tentar.

Comment: @ErlonCharles e o pior é que corremos o risco de o financeiro dizer "não era nada disso" depois :D Mas pense no lado bom, se fosse o RH, seria mais complicado ainda. Nunca vi departamento mais perdido que RH.

Comment: KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK

Comment: O financeiro pediu um relatório dos descontos dos à todos os clientes em um mês, mas alguns descontos aplicados errados foram corrigidos aplicando uma taxa de valor igual (o sistema é burro e isso foi necessário ser feito), então eu tenho q mostrar todos os descontos dados aos clientes excluindo da lista a soma dos descontos e taxa que forem 0 da lista.

Comment: isso sendo q os desconto e taxas estão na mesma tabela sendo diferenciados apenas pelos descontos serem valores negativos

Comment: Ah sim, aí pode colocar o HAVING total = 0. De qualquer forma, acrescentei as somas separadas na query pra vc ver como faz, pra não precisar complicar com subquery.

Comment: Fiz o teste e ainda tem uma coisa, os clientes q tem desconto e taxa no mesmo valor, não podem entrar no relatório, pois essa taxa é uma forma de cancelar o desconto e vice versa, não posso mostrar os clientes onde a soma entre taxa e o desconto seja 0, tenho que mostrar apenas os q são menores que 0, ou seja, os que tem desconto real aplicado. Tô tentando fazer aqui e já tô ficando com dor de cabeça.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14534/discussion-between-erlon-charles-and-bacco)

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi bem seria a Soma das Taxas, as Somas dos Descontos e depois a Diferença das duas, agrupados por cliente e data_criado:

```
SELECT a.cliente, 
       a.data_criado, 
       a.taxas, 
       a.desconto,  
       (a.taxas - abs(a.desconto)) diferenca
FROM (
SELECT cliente, data_criado, 
    sum(CASE WHEN valor > 0 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) taxas,
    sum(CASE WHEN valor < 0 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) desconto
FROM descontos_taxas
GROUP BY cliente, data_criado) as a
```

*Se ainda precisar filtrar:*

```
SELECT a.cliente, 
       a.data_criado, 
       a.taxas, 
       a.desconto,  
       (a.taxas - abs(a.desconto)) diferenca
FROM (
SELECT cliente, data_criado, 
    sum(CASE WHEN valor > 0 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) taxas,
    sum(CASE WHEN valor < 0 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) desconto
FROM descontos_taxas
GROUP BY cliente, data_criado) as a
WHERE date_format(a.data_criado, '%Y-%m') = '2014-04'
```

*Conforme solicitação a resposta*

```
SELECT a.cliente, 
       a.data_criado, 
       (a.taxas - abs(a.desconto)) valor
FROM (
SELECT cliente, data_criado, 
    sum(CASE WHEN valor > 0 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) taxas,
    sum(CASE WHEN valor < 0 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) desconto
FROM descontos_taxas
GROUP BY cliente, data_criado) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa agrupar o resultado pelo cliente e pelo dia, e precisa remover a condição `dt.valor < 0` da consulta. Ela precisa entrar como um having (que é processado após as operações). Veja:

```
SELECT 
     dt.cliente, dt.data_criado, sum(valor) AS resultado
FROM 
    descontos_taxas as dt
WHERE 
    YEAR(dt.data_criacao) = 2014 and MONTH(dt.data_criacao) = 04 
GROUP BY 
    dt.cliente, DATE_FORMAT(data_criado, "%d/%m/%Y")
ORDER BY 
    data_criado asc
HAVING
    resultado < 0;
```

Não testei a consulta, é apenas um direcionamento.

Comment: Além da data preciso também listar apenas os valores negativos (referentes a desconto)

Comment: @ErlonCharles Isso não bate com o que você disse na pergunta. Você pode editar a pergunta para esclarecer? E Arivan, considerando o texto da pergunta neste momento, parece que você só esqueceu de agrupar também por cliente.

Comment: @bfavaretto o último paragrafo diz isso "Como retornar apenas os valores negativos do resultado da soma entre taxas e descontos aplicados ao mesmo cliente no mesmo dia?"

Comment: @ErlonCharles Então acho que é só trocar `DAY(data_criacao)` por `data_criacao` nesta resposta e você consegue o resultado que quer.

Comment: isso a diferença é com agrupamento

Comment: O agrupamento não pode ser feito apenas por "data_criacao", pois ele pode ser um datetime. Pra assegura, melhor usar um DATE_FORMAT() :-).